# Weird Fluttering sound

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I have a brand new Jackson JS30, and I am already having issues with a weird fluttering sound when I pull of from 15 to 14, 9 to 8, 8 to 7, etc. I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem, yet I have had this same problem on three guitars. I have tried it on multiple amps, and with different cords, as well as taking it to the shop multiple times. Here is a link to the sound. "https://soundcloud.com/porter-larson/fret-fluttering/s-p9y5f"

Comment: I've had similar things like that happen to me and it ended up being caused by low voltage out of the wall socket, it might be worth checking it out with a VOM meter.

Comment: There are two different notes playing after you pull off. Are you definitely muting all of the other strings? What if you wrap a cloth or towel around the neck at frets 1-3 and then try the pull offs, do you still have the problem?

Comment: I don't still have the problem when I wrap the cloth, but even when I palm mute the other strings (w/out the cloth) it still happens. Also I have a floyd rose w/ a locking nut

Comment: It's really difficult to tell w/o seeing and touching the guitar but here are a couple things.  It actually sounds similar to a fast beat frequency for 2 notes out of tune.  Are you sure you are playing a single note clean?  Try the following, 1. Play with the amp clean (no effects), 2. try acoustically and see if the sound persists.  That may sound strange for an electric but it would help identify any mechanical issues, is this Jackson solid body or semi hollow?

Comment: It doesnt happen when it is on clean or acoustic, and it is a solid body. It seems to only be an issue on the b string and yes i recorded it fast so I didn't do a great job but it happens with only one "clean" note as well

Comment: If you don’t have the problem with the cloth wrapped then there are two possibilities, 1) you’re hitting another string when you pull off and it’s making a second note and 2) the string is resonating between the fretted note and the nut. The second is rare but can happen. The first is very common. Either way, I would take it back to the store and **play it in front of them with an amp** and let them tell you if it’s 1) or 2). Or you could post extensive videos here and we could *try* to tell you but that probably won’t work.

Comment: Also you should be muting with your fretting hand as well as your picking hand. Are you doing that?

Comment: @Tetsujin - I suppose a Camper-van might have low voltage problems, but I ran into this problem when playing in a bar in the mountains above Boulder, and again a couple of years later at an old theatre in Milwaukee. Low voltage can happen because of old wiring and it can create the strangest problematic effects.

Comment: I think you may very well be right - I have had some problems with other mistakes being amplified only on the distorted channel.

Comment: You say you've had the same problem with 3 different guitars. I'd say that proves there's nothing wrong with the guitar. There's a simple fault finding technique. You replace each component in turn until you find the faulty one. You could do this in a friendly music store. If it isn't the equipment then it's you!

Answer (score 2):

I highly suspect that the issue here is inadequate muting technique.

You said that you are muting the strings, but we also know that:

1. This problem happens on three different guitars,
2. The audio you shared sounds exactly like extra unmuted strings ringing out,
3. The extra notes that ring out are G, A, and D, which are easily excitable natural harmonics on the EADGBE-tuned guitar, and
4. The fluttering can be stopped with additional muting help from a cloth.

This is strong evidence toward a problem with your muting technique.

Next time you hear a flutter, touch each string with your right hand.  Hopefully you will find that touching one of the strings stops the flutter.  That's the string that you failed to mute.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a nothing burger, but distortions and beat frequencies can be caused by pick-ups too close to the strings. I had a similar distortion on my Peavey Raptor cured by increasing the distance. I don't know if this applies to Humbuckers, but for single coil pick-ups, a starting spacing of 2mm (at the e string) and 2.4mm (at the E string) between the pick-up's magnet and the bottom of the string (this from a video I watched on a Strat setup). Oh, if you have an electronic caliper for measuring, a cool trick to get that elusive distance between string and fret or string and pick-up is to measure the diameter of the string in question and zero the caliper. This now allows you to measure from top of the string to the fret or pick-up while reading the distance from bottom of string to the fret/pick-up. BTW, these calipers are really cheap these days! I just looked and Amazon shows them for as little as $9.99 (although I'd pay closer to $25 to get some quality) Neiko makes a decent one for $20 (Mine's a $150 Mitutoyo). Good Luck & Great Playing!